# Datatables S.no render issue

Tags: jquery, datatables, rendering, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I have S.No in the first column in datatable with following render code

```
 "render" : function(data, type, full, meta) {                                           
        return '<input type="radio" id="parRadio" value="'+ full+'" name="parRadio" />';
   }
```

S.No is showing perfectly but while export into pdf or excel S.No count is not proper and it's not resetting the value.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.  It has a select box in the second column.  If I don't do anything, it puts every value in the select box in the excel sheet instead of the actual value.

I use an event handler to keep the table data and the select box in sync.

I then use the customizeData callback to fix the data.

http://jsbin.com/solipe/edit?js,output

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        // create fake column to put in selectbox
        for (var i = 0; i < dataStore.data.length; ++i) {
            var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            dataStore.data[i].groupId = b;
        }

        $('#example').DataTable({
            "data": dataStore.data,
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "groupId" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
            ], dom: 'Bfrtip',
            columnDefs: [{
                // adds a selectobs to the second column
                targets: [1], render: function (a, b, c, d) {
                    var str = "";
                    for (var j = 1; j < 11; ++j) {
                        str += "<option " + (j == a ? " selected " : "") + "  value='" + j + "'>" + j + "</option>";
                    }
                    str = "<select >" + str + "</select>";
                    return str;
                }
            }],
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Save as Excel',
                // updates the data before being sent to excel
                customizeData: function (a, b, c, d) {
                    var exd = a.body;
                    var dtdata = $('#example').DataTable().rows().data();
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < dtdata.length ; ++ii) {
                        var cur = dtdata[ii].groupId;
                        exd[ii][1] = cur;
                    }

                }
            }
            ]
        });
        // Event Handler for keeping the data object in sync with the selectbox
        $("#example").on("change", "select", function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var rowData = $("#example").DataTable().rows($(this).closest("tr")).data();
            rowData[0].groupId = val;
        });
    });
```